# Can't get page orientation while exporting Excel from HTML

Tags: html, export-to-excel

I am exporting my Excel file from HTML. Everything is working but Page Orientation (Landscape).

This is my code:

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">>
<head>
<style>
<!--
@page
    {
    mso-page-orientation:landscape;
    size:landscape;
}
-->
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
        <x:ExcelWorkbook>
            <x:ExcelWorksheets>
                <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                    <x:Name>Sheet 1</x:Name>
                    <x:WorksheetOptions>
                             <x:FitToPage/> 
                            <x:Print> 
                            <x:FitWidth>1</x:FitWidth> 
                            <x:FitHeight>1000</x:FitHeight> 
                            <x:ValidPrinterInfo/> 
                            </x:Print> 
                    </x:WorksheetOptions>
                </x:ExcelWorksheet>
            </x:ExcelWorksheets>
        </x:ExcelWorkbook>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

But the page (Mac Office 2011) is always printing in Portrait Orientation and does not adapt to page width.

Any tip?

Thanks

Fabio

Comment: Have you tried printing your file by MS Excel on Windows, I tried and the Page Orientation: landscape was still ok.

Maybe this problem only occurs on Mac Office?